# fit with lsqcurvefit does not work maybe function maldefined

Tags: matlab, function, definition

I am trying to fit function F to experimental data.
x_tem and yd are both vectors of size (12,1). The function should find the best
fitting value y_tau of the function to the experimental data.
I just can't find the mistake - matlab is showing me the error :

```
Error in lsqcurvefit (line 199)
initVals.F = feval(funfcn_x_xdata{3},xCurrent,XDATA,varargin{:});
```

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. LSQCURVEFIT cannot continue.

The code is:

```
x_tem=Temp_aero_korrektur(:,1);
yd=Temp_aero_korrektur(:,2);

F = @(y_tau,x_tem)((-1)*((273.15-x_tem)*(273.15-y_tau(1))*8.314*    (((17.62*x_tem)/(243.12+x_tem))-((17.62*y_tau(1))/(243.12+y_tau(1)))))/(40714.53)); 

yd_tau = lsqcurvefit(F,-40,x_tem,yd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities here. One is that you do actually want to use matrix operations in your objective function (so that, for example, `x_tem/x_tem` gives a single scalar value using [mrdivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html)). If this is the case then you should be calling lsqcurvefit with the transpose of x_tem

```
yd_tau = lsqcurvefit(F,-40,x_tem',yd);
```

The other option is that you actually meant to calculate your objective function on each value of x_tem (so, for example, using x_tem./x_tem to give a vector the same length as x_tem). If this is the case then your objective function should be

```
F = @(y_tau,x_tem)((-1)*((273.15-x_tem).*(273.15-y_tau(1)).*8.314.*    (((17.62*x_tem)./(243.12+x_tem))-((17.62*y_tau(1))/(243.12+y_tau(1)))))/(40714.53))
```

(See documentation for [times](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) and [rdivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) for element-wise operations)

Comment: I did the second possible way, now i get the following promt:

Local minimum possible.

lsqcurvefit stopped because the final change in the sum of squares relative to 
its initial value is less than the default value of the function tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>


Optimization stopped because the relative sum of squares (r) is changing
by less than options.TolFun = 1.000000e-06.

Optimization Metric                                  Options
relative change r =   8.95e-09              TolFun =   1e-06 (default)

Do I need to shift the minimum?

Comment: Or do I have to use another fit function as lsqcurvefit??

Comment: The message you got does not necessarily mean that there was a problem. The algorithm just has no way to know for sure if it found the "correct" solution. You could try different starting values for y_tau and see if you get different results. If you have access to [Multistart](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/multistartclass.html) ([lsqcurvefit example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/multistart-using-lsqcurvefit-or-lsqnonlin.html)) it may help.